# Python: get last command line in linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I would like to write a python script which access the last command executed in terminal, i.e the command that launched the program.

For example, I want the terminal to output 'python myfile.py' if i typed `python myfile.py`

First I tried:

```
    import os
    os.system("touch command.txt")
    os.system("history > command.txt")
    with open("command.txt", "r") as f:
        command = f.read()[-1]
    print(command)
```

but this is not working since history is a bash built-in function.

Then I tried :

```
    import os, subprocess
    command = subprocess.check_output(["tail","-n","1",os.path.expanduser("~/.bash_history")]).decode("utf-8").rstrip()
    print(command)
```

but this does not meet my expectations, because bash history is only updated when the terminal is closed.

To improve this behavior I tried `os.putenv("PROMPT_COMMAND", "history-a")`, but it didn't help neither, because bash history update is still one step behind, as my variable command would now contain the command line just before `python myfile.py`

Now I'm stuck and I need your help pls

Comment: There are **much** easier ways to find your own command line than trying to read shell history (a program isn't always launched by a shell _at all_; there may not *be* such a thing as a shell command that ran it; and moreover, there's no guarantee that the user will be using bash or an other _specific_ shell).

Comment: ..._generally_, the Right Thing is to rely on `sys.argv` -- which doesn't depend on there being a shell, or know or care what that shell is. What's your use case where that's insufficient?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `sys.argv` does not show the name of the interpreter.

Comment: @DYZ, ...but the interpreter name _is_ still available, so if that's your only reason for not using `sys.argv`, I'm happy to go look up the details of how to find it portably. (Non-portably, one can just get it from procfs).

Comment: @DYZ, ...ahh, the portable interpreter lookup mechanism is `sys.executable`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There we go. **But** `sys.executable` shows the full pathname. So, technically it is not the same as the name typed on the command line. I have no idea what the OP intends to do with the results, but `sys.executable` + `sys.argv` are not a verbatim representation of the command line.

Comment: @DYZ, ...continuing on the theme of "looking up bash history is a horrible idea" -- what do you expect to happen if someone runs your script in the background and then starts something else, such that the something-else is newer in history? Or if they run a single command doing something like `yourscript & run-some-other-tool` -- they probably don't want an extra copy of `run-some-other-tool` started without their knowledge or explicit consent.

Comment: @DYZ, sure -- you *can't reliably get* an exact command line, because there may not _even exist_ an exact command line as a string in the first place!  Trying to find it is a fool's errand; you might get something that works in really simple cases (or with a shell that's been explicitly configured to cooperate), but it's going to fail horribly in the tricky ones, and thus be unreliable in general.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am not the OP. So, I cannot imagine what kind of answer they are looking for when there is no command line. I would **guess** they want the shell's `argv[]`.

Comment: _nod_. `argv[0]` isn't guaranteed to be something you can put at the beginning of a command line to restart the already-running program, though -- the calling process can put _anything_ there. So, let's say you have a copy of busybox installed that was compiled with the `ls` applet, but someone deleted it to install GNU `ls` instead. If `cp` is still a busybox applet, the bash command `exec -a ls cp /tmp` will start busybox via its `cp` executable, but _tell the executable_ that it was started under the name `ls`, even though the system's _real_ `ls` is a completely different executable.

Comment: ...as long as Linux (as tagged in the question) is genuinely the only target, the easiest way to answer _all_ these questions is by interrogating procfs -- `/proc/self` has entries for your executable name _and_ your full argv.

Comment: In fact, I want to do this for a very specific project where I know that my file will be run via a command line in a shell. So bash history may not be the way to go, but I couldn't find another.

Comment: ...the _usual_ reason I see this question is someone wanting to be able to accept `myprogram *.txt` and reevaluate the `*.txt` glob later, but the Right Answer is just to make users quote, as `myprogram '*.txt'`.

Comment: @eru, since it's targeted to a specific use case and deployment environment, can you have the shell's configuration updated to have a function wrapper loaded? (I'm basically proposing something similar to how tools like `npm` are deployed, where there's a file one sources into the script it'll be invoked from ahead-of-time).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think so, but there's no need to do this as I just tried `sys.argv` (didn't know about it before) and indeed it perfectly fulfills the task I wanted to perform ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags that you applied. Also, keep in mind that this depends on the shell that is used and for that there's no standard. Even on Linux, you can't assume Bash. Furthermore, there isn't even something like a "Linux terminal".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, ...well, I'd argue that there is such a thing, but that the phrase properly refers to the native "virtual console" support the kernel has for implementing a terminal that outputs directly to an attached display device (without going through a GUI framework or such). Fully agreed that it has no relevance to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the original shell command line in a reliable way without participation of the shell itself, but you can generate an equivalent command line using `sys.argv`. (It won't include things like redirections, but if you're just re-executing *from inside the existing copy of the program*, all those executions will have been already performed before you're started anyhow, so when you re-exec yourself the new copy will inherit their effect).

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os.path, sys
try:
    from shlex import quote  # Python 3
except ImportError:
    from pipes import quote  # Python 2

sys_argv_str = ' '.join(quote(x) for x in sys.argv)

print("We can be restarted by calling the argv: %r" % (sys.argv,))
print("As a shell-syntax string, that would be: %s" % (sys_argv_str,))
print("...or, if your shell is bash, you can specify the interpreter directly:")
print('   ' + ' '.join(quote(x) for x in (['exec', '-a', sys.argv[0], os.path.abspath(sys.executable), os.path.abspath(__file__)] + sys.argv[1:])))
```

---

If someone calls `./yourprogram "first argument" "second argument"`, that output might look like:

```
We can be restarted by calling the argv: ['./yourprogram', 'first argument', 'second argument']
As a shell-syntax string, that would be: ./yourprogram 'first argument' 'second argument'
...or, if your shell is bash, you can specify the interpreter directly:
   exec -a ./yourprogram /usr/bin/python /home/charles/tmp/yourprogram 'first argument' 'second argument'
```

Note that `argv[0]` is *not* guaranteed to be identical to `__file__`! When a program is starting another program it can pass any string it likes in the `argv[0]` slot; it's merely *convention*, not a firm guarantee, that that will contain the name that was used to start the software at hand.